# Unity Spawning GameObjects with Hinge Joints

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics-engine

I'm working on a level generator in Unity for an endless runner and I want to spawn some prefabs with hinge joints.

The trouble is that when I spawn an object with a hinge joint, it retains the anchor and connected anchor from when the prefab was saved, not relative to its spawned position.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with adding an Rigid Body(IsKinematic=true) as parent and set the `Connected Rigidy Body` property to this. Spawning the parent keeps the `Connected Anchor` in place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the joint in the prefab. Why don't you use the `AddComponent<HingeJoint>` method in runtime when you generate the level to do the connections.

Comment: I guess I can do that, but I'd like to use the Unity Editor to set the hinge properties rather than extrapolate all of the properties using my own variables on a script.

I'm surprised there isn't a quick work around that I can do to move the hinge position at runtime. Perhaps I'll do a combination, saving the hinge properties on Awake(), destroying the original hinge, then attaching a new hinge with the new properties.